# How can I implement a random page button in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I made the random page button by adding the following code to the `Template.php` skin file.

```php
Html::rawElement( 'a', [ 
    'id' => 'random',
    'class' => 'random',
    'href' => './index.php?title=Special:Random'
] )
```

But I don't like the `'href'` part. Is there a way to write it like `'href' => $this->data['nav_urls']['mainpage']['href']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, for what exactly you want to use it, however, the easiest part to replace the static linking to `index.php?title=Special:Random` would be to use the title object and let it generate a link for you. In your case something like this:

`SpecialPage::getTitleFor( 'Random' )->getLinkURL()`

in your full example:

```
Html::rawElement( 'a', [ 
    'id' => 'random',
    'class' => 'random',
    'href' => SpecialPage::getTitleFor( 'Random' )->getLinkURL()
] );
```